# Rails helper method is working where it is not supposed to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Inside my `helper/posts_helper.rb` file, I'm defining a method such like this:

```
module PostsHelper
    def testing(test)
        "Yep its a #{test}"
    end
end
```

I assume that this testing helper should work only inside my posts views. But it works at all of my views, even views of other resources of my application. I'm not putting this in `application_helper.rb`. How come it happens?

Here is my `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Comment: In ApplicationController there may be helper :all a line.

Comment: Check the include_all_helpers config to false in development.rb

Comment: I have nothing about helpers inside any of my environment files. Neither Development, nor Production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common misconception that Rails will only load the helpers for a specific controller. By default, Rails will load all helpers. You need to set this line in your application.rb:

`config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false`

This will only load the helpers that you expect (the one for your controller and anything in it's inheritance chain, such as ApplicationHelper etc).

Comment: Oh really? But it really doesn't seems to be a "Rails way". It's almost against OOP's encapsulation metodology. Really. Weired. 

Thanks for your answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `helper :all` somewhere, such as your application controller.